# How to create an analog power source?

Tags: power-supply, analog, signal-generator

I'm in the process of building a signal generator using the [AD9833](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad9833.pdf). It requires a dedicated analog power supply, but I'm not entirely clear on how to devise such a power supply.

From various resources like textbooks and open-source projects, I've observed that analog power supplies are often fashioned by integrating some inductors and capacitors (forming a low-pass filter) after a digital power supply, akin to the diagram below.

[image: An analog power supply from open-source project]

I'm uncertain about how to determine the appropriate specifications of these components. Additionally, if this portion of the circuit indeed serves as a low-pass filter, how should I manage the power supply if the frequencies of my digital and analog components are similar?

Comment: `some ICs` what ICs? Links to datasheets please, or at least part numbers?

Comment: It depends on what kind of analog supply you need.

Comment: The analog power supply is not a power supply that's analog, or a supply of analog power - it's a supply of power for the analog part of the circuit. The reason that part gets its own power supply is so you can try to keep it noise-free. You can just directly connect them, but you will probably have more noise than you could have had. If you add a filter to reduce noise, the general rule will be that you want as much filtering as possible, and there are diminishing returns.

Comment: Contrary to your claims, the AD9833 has only single supply pin that powers the analog and digital sections inside the chip. So the chip does not require separate digital and analog supplies. Can you be more specific what circuit you mean if you say it needs a digital and analog supplies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the AD9833 doesn't require an "Analog Power Supply" it just has both an Analog and a Digital ground pin, for PCBs that separate the ground planes. You don't have to worry about it. If you want to avoid switching noise in the PSU you can have a linear LDO regulator supplying VDD to the AD9833.

I believe I tried to use this chip back in 2010 and could not get it to perform as advertised. I spent many hours on the phone to tech support at ADI with a result of "maybe our chip doesn't work" being the final word. Perhaps you'll have better luck.

Of further note, the digital "Word" that determines frequency is not a linear progression. By which I mean that if you instantiate a counter and update the frequency using it, the output frequency will not necessarily increase with each increasing count. So there was a bit of back and forth in the forums about roadmapping the correct sequence of words to send to get a smooth frequency sweep.

It has been 14 years, maybe they have fixed the issues I experienced. Your mileage may vary.

---

A further comment on having separate analog and digital ground planes.
Robert Feranec with Rick Hartley:
Watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vALt6Sd9vlY&t=6s

Comment: The separate analog and digital ground pins are not so much an invitation to have separate ground planes, but rather to connect them together at a sensible point *outside* the IC package. https://www.analog.com/en/resources/analog-dialogue/articles/staying-well-grounded.html

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much noise the VDD line puts out, if it's on a switcher and the inductor won't be sufficient at filtering, a low noise LDO would be a better option. There is no PSRR rating in the AD9833 datasheet, but it does say that it needs a 0.1uF and 10uF cap and it has it's own power supply that operates at Vcc/2